# CakePHP - Table naming conventions (over more than one table)

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions

What is the right plural/singular table naming convention in CakePHP.

This:
posts
posts_pictures
posts_picture_captions <-- Not sure about this

Or this:
posts
posts_pictures
posts_pictures_captions <-- Not sure about this

I know CakePHP want the tables in alphabetical order but this should in this question ignored. Please only consider plural/singular table naming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the cakephp book:

> Model class names are singular and CamelCased. Person, BigPerson, and
>   ReallyBigPerson are all examples of conventional model names.
>
> Table names corresponding to CakePHP models are plural and
>   underscored. The underlying tables for the above mentioned models
>   would be people, big_people, and really_big_people, respectively.
>
> You can use the utility library Inflector to check the singular/plural
>   of words. See the Inflector for more information.
>
> Field names with two or more words are underscored: first_name.
>
> Foreign keys in hasMany, belongsTo or hasOne relationships are
>   recognized by default as the (singular) name of the related table
>   followed by _id. So if a Baker hasMany Cake, the cakes table will
>   refer to the bakers table via a baker_id foreign key. For a table like
>   category_types whose name contains multiple words, the foreign key
>   would be category_type_id.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

So at first, your "posts_pictures" table should be named "post_pictures".
As a result, neither of the two is correct. The correct name according to the cake naming conventions is "post_picture_captions".

Comment: You need to finish quoting the page. `Join tables, used in hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) relationships between models, should be named after the model tables they will join, arranged in alphabetical order (apples_zebras rather than zebras_apples).` So if posts_pictures is a JOIN table it is correct by the standards (assuming per the OP that alphabetical order does not matter.)

Comment: That is not a HABTM-Relation, its only a hasMany over more tables.

Answer (score 2):

[Cake Inflector](http://inflector.cakephp.org/) Should do exactly what you are looking to do.

Comment: +1 Incredible. I am a CakePHP beginner and I was asking myself if their engine indeed inflects such words like 'companies' correctly. With you link I see they solved this problem and it helps me a lot. Such a non-descript link with lot of power. Thx!